# why is this oscillator not working?

Tags: oscillator

[Falstad link](http://tinyurl.com/jfx3zyf)

I've taken this oscillator from [an introduction book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1680450263). I've more or less understood the explanation in this book for this circuit, but in practice, it doesn't work: the LED should be flashing on and off each second.

Comment: What oscillator? That's a simple LED with battery and variable resistor.

Comment: sorry, wrong link, I've edited the Falstad link

Comment: Increase the base resistors from 470 to 47K - or some value significantly larger than the collector resistors. Or interchange them - Rc=470, Rb=4k7. It's running now even though the transistors are matched.

Comment: That's good! I would validate your answer if you post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're simulating it your transistors are perfectly matched. You actually need mismatched transistors (betas maybe 10% different) for oscillators like this to work.

Comment: for example Q1 at 100 and Q2 at 120? but it doesn't change anything

Comment: change your base resistors to a higher value as Brian said in the above comments.

Comment: There needs to be an imbalance in the circuit for it to start oscillating so when you build this you would test your beta values and use transistors that aren't matched. I don't know what your book says about how it works but if you want to look it up this circuit is called an astable multivibrator

Comment: You should also be able to solve this by mismatching the resistors.